# How to show content of a custom block using PHP code format in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have added some custom code in a block using PHP code format to show that block on a specific page. I have checked all the things working fine on Devel PHP page but contents are not showing on page. The code below fetches the field value of a destination node.

```
    $refer = $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER];
    $parsed = parse_url($refer);
    $alias = array_pop($parsed);
    $dst = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($alias , $langcode);
    $nid = array_pop(explode('/', $dst));
    $dest_node = node_load($nid);

    $body = $dest_node->get('body')->getValue();
    print $body; //have tried other printing methods also but invain
```

Hope this clarifies the question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it works in Devel? I've just tried to execute your code, and this line:

```
$body = $dest_node->get('body')->getValue();
```

returns *Array*.

Try to use this one instead:

```
$body = $dest_node->body->value;
```

Comment: @Zubi It will work only on nodes' pages (i. e. "node/123" or an alias). So you mean it works sometime exactly on these nodes' pages (on some nodes works and on some nodes doesn't)? If the page is a kind of a View, it will obviously not work.

Comment: I checked the log it gives error for this line
         ` $nid = array_pop(explode('/', $dst));`

Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in eval()

Comment: and yes I used it for node pages.

Comment: Could you please provide an alias for the node that causes this error.

Comment: its a contact page "/contact"

Comment: yes Sorry, its not a node. What could be the solution to get destination node's ID.

Comment: Right now this node's id is taken from URL. URL contains node's id if the current page is actually a node. If the current page is not a node (like a page that was generated via a module, like /contact page, or a View), then I don't know what this destination node id should be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your first block of code (getting current node) can be replaced with just one line:

```
$node = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getParameter('node');
```

And the whole block can be changed in the following way:

```
if ($node = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getParameter('node')) {
  print $node->body->value;
}
```

P.S. And it's definitely a bad idea to use PHP text filter. You may easily write your own custom module providing required block. The simplest block plugin requires several lines of code:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block\MyBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides my super block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "my_module_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("My Block"),
 *   category = @Translation("My Module"),
 * )
 */

class MyBlock extends BlockBase{

  /**
   * Builds and returns the renderable array for this block plugin.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A renderable array representing the content of the block.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder
   */
  public function build() {
    if ($node = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getParameter('node')) {
      return [ '#markup' => $node->body->value ];
    }
  }
}
```

This file `MyBlock.php` must be placed in `/src/Plugin/Block/` directory inside your custom module named `my_module`.